# Simple Math based captcha

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, captcha, recaptcha

reCaptcha is now difficult to read (decipher actually). So I am looking for an alternative captcha system to use.

I am thinking of using a simple Math based system, for example : "`What is 2+5`".

Are there any such plugins, or, ideas on how to build my own?

(Not complicated math [like this one](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ceejayoz/2674227920/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried a captcha method like mine below?

[what are the downpoints of this captcha method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207135/what-are-the-downpoints-of-this-captcha-method/)

or are you specifically wanting to use a user-entry method?

Answer (score 2):

PHP - Generates a simple addition or subtraction math question, randomly alternating between displaying numbers (10 - 3) and words (seven plus five) and accepts answers numerically (14) or as words (fourteen).  Returns an array representing the components of the equation

[0] - first variable value, as string, like either '4' or 'four'
[1] - second value, the operator, like '+' or 'plus'
[2] - third value, the second variable, like 'ten' or '10'
[3] - the answer, in numerical form, like '14'
[4] - the answer, in text form, like 'fourteen'

So just print the equation to the page, store the array in $_SESSION, and then check the answer the user provides.

```
<?php

// array of numbers and their corresponding word versions
// you can simply do $wordNumbers[6] and get 'six'
$wordNumbers = array(
    0 => 'zero',
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3 => 'three',
    4 => 'four',
    5 => 'five',
    6 => 'six',
    7 => 'seven',
    8 => 'eight',
    9 => 'nine',
    10 => 'ten',
    11 => 'eleven',
    12 => 'twelve',
    13 => 'thirteen',
    14 => 'fourteen',
    15 => 'fifteen',
    16 => 'sixteen',
    17 => 'seventeen',
    18 => 'eighteen',
    19 => 'nineteen', 
    20 => 'twenty'
);

/*
 * 
 * returns an array representing components of a math captcha
 *  [0] - first variable value, as string, like either '4' or 'four'
 *  [1] - second value, the operator, like '+' or 'plus'
 *  [2] - third value, the second variable, like 'ten' or '10'
 *  [3] - the answer, in numerical form, like '14'
 *  [4] - the answer, in text form, like 'fourteen'
 */
function getMathCaptcha(){

    global $wordNumbers;

    $equation = array();

    // get first number, between 7 and 13 inclusive
    $n1 = rand(7, 13);
    $r = rand(0,1);
    // return $n1 as digit or text
    if ($r == 0) {
        $equation[0] = $n1;
    } else {
        $equation[0] = $wordNumbers[$n1];
    }

    // get operator
    $o = rand(0,1);
    $r = rand(0,1);
    if ($o == 0){
        // subtraction
        if ($r == 0) {
            $equation[1] = '-';
        } else {
            $equation[1] = 'minus';
        }
    } else {
        // addition
        if ($r == 0) {
            $equation[1] = '+';
        } else {
            $equation[1] = 'plus';
        }
    }

    // get second number, between 0 and 7 inclusive, so no negative answers
    $n2 = rand(1,7);
    $r = rand(0,1);
    // return $n2 as digit or text
    if ($r == 0) {
        $equation[2] = $n2;
    } else {
        $equation[2] = $wordNumbers[$n2];
    }

    // get answer
    if ($o == 0){
        $answer = $n1 - $n2;
    } else {
        $answer = $n1 + $n2;
    }

    // answer as digit and text
    $equation[3] = $answer;
    $equation[4] = $wordNumbers[$answer];


    return $equation;

}


?>
```

Comment: Judging by the ASP.NET tag you're not working in PHP but the logic is pretty obvious and it should be simple to port to whatever language you like.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Captchator](http://captchator.com/)?

It's easy to implement and it just works! There are also code samples for PHP and Ruby out there, shouldn't be difficult to implement in other languages.

Math based captchas are weak and easy to pass, there are many spambots out there that know how to do the math :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were to make a simple one, it would go along the lines of:

Make different items of categories, such as flowers, fruits, vegetables, and meats. Then design the captcha to ask for a total of a category.

For example:

Randomize the categories, choose 2 unique ones. So perhaps we got flowers and fruits.Next, ask the user: "If you have 3 roses, 4 oranges, and 6 apples, then how many fruits do you have?"

Simple pattern:

Get n-1 unique categories. Show n items, where each item belongs to one of the unique categories. Ask for a total from one category.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a captcha like this on your own. All you have to do is create a function which will pick up a random number between the given list of numbers and call the function twice to pick up two random numbers.

Store the result in a session variable or any other variable so that you can verify it later.

below is an example coded in c#

```
    Random a=new Random();
    a.Next();//it will return you a non negative number
    a.Next(min value,maximum value);//it will return you a number between the range specified.
```

Hope this helps