# what are the downpoints of this captcha method

Tags: html, css, captcha, spam-prevention

I use this captcha method on all my forms on many sites, the basic premis is that I have a text box that is hidden by css, if the server-side code determines that there is any content in this box, then the form is not completed.

Client side:

```
<li id="li-cap"><label>Leave this field blank</label><input type="text" maxlength="30" id="cap" name="cap" /></li>
```

Css:

```
#li-cap{display:none}
```

Server side psuedo code:

```
if(!nullOrEmpty(input#cap))
{
    return post back to form with error
}
else
{
    process form
}
```

**this is ignoring any clientside validation for the moment**

I've been using this form of captcha (i believe it has a name, can't remember it though, think it begins with p) for a while now, and i'm seeing lots of different kinds of captchas around: mathematical sums, random letters on images, questions.

My version requires no entry from the user, and I get no spam forms at all. Is this actually a good method, or am I just a bit lucky? Should I be using a stronger method?

Comment: I am using the same method and is working like a charm. I get no bots/forms spam. Only down side to me is that site based bots still spam but that amount is so low that I can live with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of captcha is relatively strong for typical spambots, that fill all the fields. However, it is completely inefficient for site-based floodbots, and this is why it will not be used on high-audience websites.

Comment: what would you class as a high-audience website?

Comment: Just sites which could attract script-kiddies or haters, I guess. Not only high-audience websites, but it’s a fact: the more visitors you have, the more haters you get.